# Symfony2 blank page

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Using Symfony2, Doctrine2 and MySQL, I am going through some trouble.

Imagine some simple doctrine generated entity with 14 elements in database that have to be listed in a certain myPage document.

I perform the request from the browser and I DO GET into the myPage controller method. The method is executed from the beginning to the end (I see this in the logs), fetching every element and preparing them to be returned in an array. Finally the controller properly generates the Response and returns it. I write that Response object in the logs and looks perfect.

But, surprise!, all what I get in the browser is a blank page:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Incredibly, If I remove ANY of the elements to be fetched and listed in the browser, so instead of having 14, I list 13, the page just "comes to life" and it is perfectly browsed. Note that in both cases every log shows exactly the same. The controller is executed from A to Z and the response is properly formed and returned equally.

Both server and browser cache has been brightly cleaned dozens of times.

---

Edit (some experiments):
Removing all variables and writing just a basic HTML page, it is properly browsed:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>Hello world!</body>
</html>
```

Inserting a `trans-endtrans` label, it works. This browsers the page:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Hello world! One fine translation: {% trans %}one.fine.translation{% endtrans %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Inserting a second `trans-endtrans` label, blank page!! This gives a blank page:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Hello world!
        One fine translation: {% trans %}one.fine.translation{% endtrans %}
        Second fine translation: {% trans %}second.fine.translation{% endtrans %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Inserting a simple twig variable, blank page!! This gives a blank page:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Hello world!
        {{ my_variable }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Again, if I just remove one register of those that have to be listed in the page, it works always.

---

Edit 2 (more details):

Any time I clear cache, it seems to work once. But only once! i.e.:

1. I request the page
2. I get the famous blank page
3. I clear cache (`rm -rf app/cache`)
4. I reload the page
5. The page is browsed properly!!!
6. I reload again
7. I awfully get again the blank and so I do any additional time that I reload the page.

So... anything to do with Symfony cache????

---

I am not really faithful on having a super-accurated answer to solve my problem. I just wonder if any of you readers sometime passed through a so weird issue and if you saw anything in the doctrine relations that might be causing it.

It also would be helpful some other ways to check other logs where I could find what is causing this mess. Apache.error.log doesn't shows much. Any doctrine log? I really don't know where else to look for my solution.

Or any other configurations or anything to do with Symfony2 cache??

Comment: Probably something in your Twig view. Try removing the variables trying to access your objects

Comment: Ok, I'll try this. But I don't think it will solve anything, because as I said I write in the log the complete generated response (which is generated from the twig template). That is the last step in the controller right before returning such response. Anyway, I'll try something around that and I'll say what I get. Thanks again

Comment: Yeah sorry to be of little help, I clearly remember hitting my head against the wall because of the same exact problem, but I can't remember the solution...

Comment: I know it's something with corrupt data... But don't get exactly what... I'll let you know if I solve it

Comment: Anyway Doctrine should be a little softer when things like this happen.

Comment: Did you try to completely delete the cache folder? rm -rf app/cache

Comment: Yes. Many times. And I'll tell you what happens: every time I delete de cache, it works properly ONCE. Just once. Therefor, I clear cache, I reload, everything goes well and the page is browsed, and then I reload the page and, suprise!!, the page is already gone. Blank page!!. I think it is a good point to edit again my original question. Any clue on this?? Thanks a lot for your interest.

Comment: Sounds like it could be an issue with permissions on your cache directory, try to ```chmod 777 app/cache```

Comment: Yes, I already did. Actually, I have advanced a little on the knowledge of the problem. I seems more serious than what I thought and it probably has to do with memory usage. In the controller, I have commented some of the lines of code where object are fetched through entity relations. Things like $entity1->getEntities2(), where there is a relationship 1 to N from entity1 and entity2. Returning as well less data to the twig template. Doing this I get the page to render properly as many times as I reload. I'll write further information as soon as I research a little more. I'll let you know! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

I finally got it to work.

It definitely was a problem with memory. I think Doctrine2 sometimes doesn't manage the memory well.

It was really tricky because I was getting the error in my testing environment, where no error was shown in any log, debug bar or displayed in the screen.

Once I got to reproduce the same error in local, I saw pretty quickly the exact line of code were the error was taking place.

So, kids, when you have a completely blank page, consider that you may be troubleshooting some memory problem and manage to reproduce the error in some environment were you know that logging is working properly.